# sort values inside loop javasccript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I spent a good 30 minutes looking on this site trying to find an answer to this problem however what ever I seem to try won't fix it.

```
        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
         var msg_pop = '<div class="info_window" style="cursor: pointer;" >'; 
         msg_pop += result[i].name + '<br/> ';
         msg_pop +=  result[i].team_member + '<br/> ';
         msg_pop +=  result[i].university + '<br/> ';
         msg_pop += '</div>';
        //alert(result[i].address);
   }
```

This is the data i get inside for loop

```
     loop 1
      -------
         name0
         member0
         university0
         address0

      loop 2
      -------
         name1
         member1
         university1
         address1

      loop 3
      -------
         name2
         member2
         university2
         address0

      loop 4
      -------
         name3
         member3
         university3
         address1

      loop 5
      -------
         name4
         member4
         university4
         address0
```

Need to get result like

### result

```
loop1
------
address0

    name0
    member0
    university0
    ------------
    name2
    member2
    university2
    ------------
    name4
    member4
    university4
loop 2
-------
address1

    name1
    member1
    university1
    -------------
    name3
    member3
    university3
```

I need a javascript for loop to get the values inside the loop if its repeated by address.

Comment: How is the data you treat in the loop? I mean, what structure you have before the loop?

Comment: You need to look as if you've at least attempted to solve this yourself. SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: sorry for that its not like i have not tried , i have updated the code. please help!!!

Comment: The piece of code you're showing isn't enough to understand either what you have or what you need. What is the `result` variable?

Comment: @Nico thanks for your reply in result is an object where name,team_member,university,address comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go through your array and group them by address.

```
var by_address = {};
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var address = result[i].address;
    if (!by_address[address]) {
        by_address[address] = [];
    }
    by_address[address].push(result[i]);
}
```

Then you can loop through the `by_address` object:

```
var msg_pop = '';
for (var addr in by_address) {
    msg_pop += '<div>' + addr;
    for (var i = 0; i < by_address[addr].length; i++) {
        msg_pop += '<div class="info_window" style="cursor: pointer;" >'; 
        msg_pop += by_address[addr].name + '<br/> ';
        msg_pop += by_address[addr].team_member + '<br/> ';
        msg_pop += by_address[addr].university + '<br/> ';
        msg_pop += '</div>';
    }
    msg_pop += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks i tried with this and it worked.

```
for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
var msg_pop = '<div class="info_window" style="cursor: pointer;" >'; 
    for(j=0;j<result.length;j++){

                if(result[i].address==result[j].address)
                {
                    msg_pop += '<a href="'+result[j].guid+'"> ';
                    msg_pop += result[j].name + '<br/> ';
                    msg_pop +=  result[j].team_member + '<br/> ';
                    msg_pop +=  result[j].university + '<br/></a>';
                    if(j>=1)
                    {
                    msg_pop += '<hr/> ';
                    }
                }
                }
    msg_pop += '</div>';
```

}